# Looping through the values in ansible

Tags: loops, ansible

I have below playbook which creates policy

I have parameter called policy   which has 5 values (" mirror", "vault", "mirrorandvault", "default", "XDP")

I have put `with_sequence` loop.

I want this policy to be created with each loop.

I tried ternary operator  for 2 policies

```
type: "{{ (volume_item|int < 7)|ternary('mirror', 'vault') }}
```

It worked.

I am not sure about how to implement for 5 policies.

```
- hosts: localhost

  gather_facts: false

  vars_files:

    - /etc/ansible/group_vars/host_vars

  tasks:

    - name: Create ONTAP/ONTAP SnapMirror

      na_ontap_snapmirror:

        state: present

        source_volume: "{{ vserver }}vol_{{ item }}"

        destination_volume: "{{ vserver }}vol_{{ item | int +15}}"

        source_vserver: "{{ vserver }}"

        destination_vserver: "{{ vserver }}"

        schedule: hourly

        policy:

        max_transfer_rate: 1000

        hostname: "{{ aiqumip }}"

        username: "{{ aiqumusername }}"

        password: "{{ aiqumpassword }}"

      with_sequence: start=1 end=15
```